# New custom close reason here on meta

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, meta

I've proposed the following new custom close reason for **here on Meta.Programmers**:

> The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.

This is a direct copy of the one on Meta.StackOverflow (sorry Meta.StackExchange).

If we think that it's a good idea then it can be activated by another moderator.

Comment: Do it. Do it. Do it.

Comment: For Meta, yes, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: voted to close this very question using new reason. Feels pretty meta :)